# How to recursively add subpanels in a shiny app?

Tags: shiny

I want to build a ShinyApp that can assist me in correcting student assignments. As a first step, I require an interface that enables me to define the number of exercises and sub-exercises for the specific assignment.

This is my current code:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("correction mask"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("correction",
      textOutput("feedback")
    ),
    tabPanel("settings",
      textInput("contact", "contact", value = "John Doe (mail@example.com)"),
      numericInput("exc", "number of exercises", value = 0, min = 0, step = 1),
      numericInput("pt", "number of points", value = 10, min = 1),
      uiOutput("exc")
    )
  )
)

add_exc_panel <- function(i, input, output, label = "exc_") {
  label <- paste0(label, i)
  tabPanel(
    paste("excercise", i),
    numericInput(paste0("np_", label), "number of exercises", value = 0, min = 0, step = 1),
    numericInput(paste0("pt_", label), "number of points", value = 2, min = 1),
    textAreaInput(paste0("fb_", label), "feedback", "feedback"),
    # TODO: add panels for sub-exercises
    if (!is.null(input[[paste0("np_", label)]]) && input[[paste0("np_", label)]] > 0) {
      #browser()
      render_exc_panel(input, output, input[[paste0("np_", label)]])
    },
    uiOutput(label)
  )
}

render_exc_panel <- function(input, output, label) {
  output[[label]] <- renderUI({
    do.call(
      tabsetPanel,
      lapply(seq_len(input[[label]]), add_exc_panel, input, output, label)
    )
  })
  return(output)
}


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output <- render_exc_panel(input, output, "exc")
  output$feedback <- renderText("Feedback ...")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This creates a ShinyApp where each exercise has a separate tab that is generated based on the user input for "number of exercises" in the settings tab. However, I am now trying to add sub-panels for each exercise to allow for sub-tasks.

For example, I want to be able to select "number of exercises" as 2 in the tab "exercise 1" and have two additional sub-panels appear underneath for sub-tasks 1a) and 1b). I have attempted to implement this using the `render_exc_panel()` function recursively, but it has not been successful.

Can someone suggest an approach to dynamically generating sub-panels based on user input in a ShinyApp?

Comment: I'd recommend using a hierarchical input for navigation, like the one provided by library([jsTreeR](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR)), instead of reinventing the wheel.